# Akka Alpakka SqsSource weirdly enough can work with queueUrl and also with queueName

Tags: akka, amazon-sqs, akka-stream, alpakka

Im using Akka Streams, and also alpakka.sqs.scaladsl to read messages from sqs queue.

I'v done in many times, but now I uploaded a version that put the queue name in the source instead of queue url which this was how I did it all the time.

this is how I did it before:

```
SqsSource(queue.getUrl)
```

and now I did this:

```
SqsSource(queueName)
```

both cases works..

the url prefix is identical between all queues so I figured either alpakka or AmazonSQSAsync have some implicit for this or something, does someone know how to explain this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alpakka doesn't do anything special with the queue URL. The string is passed to the AWS SQS unchanged which resolves it.